# Python speeding up nested loops with numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Hi I am trying to make a python code of YIN algorithm.

At step 3, I had to use triple for loops as code below.

```
def auto(t, lag, samples):
    total_index = len(samples)
    zero_padded = np.append(samples, np.zeros(total_index))
    # 2nd for loop changed to numpy
    return np.sum(zero_padded[t+1: t+total_index+1] * zero_padded[t+1+lag: t+total_index+1+lag])

def diff_function(lag, rt0, samples):
    return rt0 + auto(lag, 0, samples) - (2*auto(0, lag, samples))

# cumulative mean nomalized difference function
def CMN_diff_function(lag, rt0, samples):
    nomalization = 0
    for j in range(1, lag + 1):    # 3rd for loop that I want to change
        nomalization += diff_function(rt0, j, samples)
    nomalization = nomalization / lag

    return diff_function(rt0, lag, samples) / nomalization

rt0 = auto(0, 0, samples)
cmn_diff = [1]
for lag in range(1, 2700):    # 1st for loop
    print lag
    cmn_diff.append(CMN_diff_function(lag, rt0, samples))
```

I changed second for loop with numpy from auto function.

The code still slow and I need to change third for loop.

I tried to use fromfunction of numpy as code below.

```
def CMN_diff_function(lag, rt0, samples):
    nomalization = np.fromfunction(functools.partial(diff_function, rt0=rt0, samples=samples), (lag+1,), dtype=int)
    nomalization = np.sum(nomalization)/lag

    return diff_function(lag, rt0, samples)/nomalization
```

but i got error

```
return np.sum(zero_padded[t+1: t+total_index+1] * zero_padded[t+1+lag: t+total_index+1+lag])
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

since auto function get list type as a parameter of t or lag.

how can I speed up this function?

should I use multiprocessing?

Comment: The code looks like it can be easily rewriten into Cython, so if you aren't after a pure-Python solution, I'd recommend that. Also, could you provide some sample data?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev sample is a sound which length is 20000